# How to skip moodle login page when integrated with Keycloak as IDP (opend id connect)

Tags: keycloak, single-sign-on, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-boost

We are new to Moodle. We are trying to integrate our existing authentication (Keycloak) with moodle. We were able to add keycloak as an identity provider and when accessing Moodle, we can log in using the current keycloak authentication. So far good and no issues.

Now we are trying to invoke Moodle from external application (which also uses same keycloak realm). While accessing Moodle URL, it again asks for login and once logged in, it creates a separate session and token in keycloak. How do we skip this login and make moodle use the existing token available. This is SSO integration and supposed to work without religion if I am right.

We are including token in the header and we tried with setting cookies as well. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

There are lot of existing thread on similar issues, but nothing helps

We are trying to integrate our existing authentication (Keycloak) with moodle. We were able to add keycloak as an identity provider and when accessing Moodle, we can log in using the current keycloak authentication. So far good and no issues.